# How Would i put this pattern on a curved surface?

Tags: modeling

[image]
Ok, so now i have made the arch around the window.Now i am trying to place the First pattern on the curved surface.

[[image: ][2]]
I have no clue how to place it on the curved plane

Comment: Shrinkwrap Modifier. But I think that texturing it would be easier.

Comment: @Jaedan Why do you want to add an extra mesh there? Wouldn't be easier to just texture that part since there is no geometry there- just a painting?